# Dynamically created panels not responding to CSS for alignment

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, visual-studio

I am working on a website that will act as a blog. My issue is with the comments section and it deals with the alignment of child comment panels. I try to add CSS to float the panels right, but they stay on the left. I have also tried setting the HorizontalAlign of the parent panels to right.

For more context, this is an image of the comments section:

[As you can see, the child comments panels are sticking to the left.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96wGl.png)

This is the method where I am dynamically creating the comments section into an exiting panel called Panel1.

```
protected void drawComments(string ID, int NumTabs, Panel parentPanel) {
        string hash = ID;

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Secret Stuff);
        string cmdStr = "SELECT * FROM Comments WHERE ParentID=@searchHash";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdStr, conn);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@searchHash", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = hash;

        try
        {
            conn.Open();

            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            Panel tempPanel;
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    ID = reader.GetString(4);
                    tempPanel = new Panel();
                    tempPanel.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Solid;
                    tempPanel.BorderColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#2461bf");
                    tempPanel.Width = new Unit((100 - (NumTabs * 5)).ToString() + "%");
                    tempPanel.Attributes.Add("style", "margin-left:auto;");
                    tempPanel.Attributes.Add("style", "margin-right:auto;");


                    if (NumTabs > 0)
                    {
                        tempPanel.Attributes.Add("style", "margin-bottom:5px");
                        //   tempPanel.Attributes.Add("style", "border-top-style:none");
                        tempPanel.Attributes.Add("style", "border-left-style:none");
                        // tempPanel.Attributes.Add("style", "border-right-style:solid");
                        tempPanel.Attributes.Add("style", "border-bottom-style:none");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        tempPanel.Attributes.Add("style", "margin-top:50px");
                       // Panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<BR />"));
                    }
                    Label currComment = new Label();
                    Label currAuthor = new Label();
                    currComment.Text = reader.GetString(0);
                    currAuthor.Text = reader.GetString(3).Split('@')[0];


                    Table tbl = new Table();
                    tbl.Width = new Unit("100%");
                    tbl.Attributes.Add("style", "margin-left:auto");
                    tbl.Attributes.Add("style", "margin-right:auto");

                    TableRow tblrow1 = new TableRow();

                    TableCell tblcell11 = new TableCell();
                    TableCell tblcell12 = new TableCell();

                    tblcell11.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
                    tblcell11.Width = new Unit("30%");
                    tblcell11.Text = currAuthor.Text + " Says:";

                    tblcell12.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
                    tblcell12.Text = currComment.Text;
                    tblcell12.Width = new Unit("70%");

                    tblrow1.Cells.Add(tblcell11);
                    tblrow1.Cells.Add(tblcell12);
                    tbl.Rows.Add(tblrow1);

                    TableCell tblcell21 = new TableCell();
                    tblcell21.Width = new Unit("30%");

                    ImageButton replyButton = new ImageButton();
                    replyButton.ImageUrl = "~/images/replybutton.png";
                    replyButton.Attributes.Add("style", "float:right");
                    replyButton.Width = 77;
                    replyButton.ID = ID;
                    replyButton.Command += addReply;

                    ImageButton likeButton = new ImageButton();
                    likeButton.ImageUrl = "~/images/likebutton.png";
                    likeButton.Attributes.Add("style", "float:right");
                    likeButton.Width = 65;

                    Label likeCount = new Label();
                    likeCount.Attributes.Add("style", "float:right");
                    likeCount.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Groove;
                    likeCount.Text = "0";

                    TableCell tblcell22 = new TableCell();
                    tblcell22.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
                    tblcell22.Controls.Add(likeCount);
                    tblcell22.Controls.Add(likeButton);
                    tblcell22.Controls.Add(replyButton);
                    tblcell22.Width = new Unit("70%");

                    TableRow tblrow2 = new TableRow();
                    tblrow2.Cells.Add(tblcell21);
                    tblrow2.Cells.Add(tblcell22);

                    tbl.Rows.Add(tblrow2);

                    tempPanel.Controls.Add(tbl);
                    //tempPanel.Controls.Add(currComment);

                    if (NumTabs>0)
                    { 
                        parentPanel.Controls.Add(tempPanel);
                    }
                    else
                        Panel1.Controls.Add(tempPanel);



                    drawComments(reader.GetString(4), NumTabs + 1, tempPanel);

                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblDebug.Text = ex.ToString();
        }
        finally { conn.Close(); }
    }
```

Any suggestions to get these child panels right aligning would be greatly appreciated. I hope you can understand what I am going for through this poorly written code by a 15 year old.